# Failed to execute script 'pyi rth win32api' due to unhandled exception: Module 'pywintypes' isn't in frozen sys.path

Tags: python, exe

I am trying to convert my.py file into .exe file using pyinstaller.
but facing the following exception while executing .exe file.

```
Error: Failed to execute script 'pyi rth win32api' due to unhandled exception: 
    Module 'pywintypes' isn't in frozen sys.path
```

I have tried installing hidden packages as well using command:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import 'pywintypes' --onefile 'filename.py'
```

But still the same exception.

Comment: Exact same problem